# Ios simulator for maui in windows

Tags: ios-simulator, maui

I have been dealing with a very big problem for some time now, I want to debug my maui project on the ios platform, but I don't have access to the ios device and unfortunately I can't run mac on vitrual machine.

Is there an ios emulator for Windows that has debugging capabilities? (like Geny motion for Android)

Comment: No.  You need access to a Mac in order to do iOS development.

Comment: You could use [Pair to Mac for iOS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac).